# Android Coordinates

Tags: java, android

Is their a way to make it where no matter what the screen size is my sprites will always start at a certain position. I am trying to get my sprites to start in the lower right corner  area of the screen. I am using a 2D SurfaceView.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the screen size ([this StackOverflow answer says how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/android-how-to-get-screen-dimensions/1016941#1016941)) and you'll have a vector (of the [mathematical variety](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Vector.html)) representing the bottom-right coordinate of the screen. Now you can just place stuff relative to this vector in order to place things relative to the bottom-right of the screen instead of the top-left.

<sup>I'm assuming that on Android, (0,0) is the top-left corner of the screen. If it isn't, I'll edit this answer to accommodate.</sup>

---

#### In case it isn't clear how that would work, here's an explanation

*First: please make sure you have a basic understanding of vectors (not the list type, but the mathematical object). [The vector tag's description](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/tags/vector/info) links to a succinct tutorial on vectors within the context of games. Read [part one](http://blog.wolfire.com/2009/07/linear-algebra-for-game-developers-part-1/) at least. A basic understanding of vectors is critical for game programmers, if only because it will make your life easier.*

Remember that the *origin* of the screen, which sits at the top left, is `(0, 0)`. Consider that when you place something at `(30, 30)`, you're actually placing it at `(0, 0) + (30, 30)`. You're placing it at `(30, 30)` relative to a particular point on the screen - the origin.

So if you want to place something 25 pixels left and 20 pixels up from the bottom-right corner, you're placing it at `(-25, -20)` relative to the bottom-right corner. Assuming `(right, bottom)` represents the bottom-right corner of the screen, that means you just place your sprite at `(right, bottom) + (-25, -20)`.

In code, assuming you have a 2-dimensional vector class named `Vector2`, which represents a [mathematical vector](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Vector.html) (*NOT* the [vector list type](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html)!):

```
// From the StackOverflow answer linked at the beginning
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();
int height = display.getHeight();

// This is the coordinate of the bottom-right most pixel on the screen
Vector2 bottomRight = new Vector2(width, height);

// This is the position you want the sprite relative to the bottom-right point
// (25 pixels left, 20 pixels up)
Vector2 distFromBR = new Vector2(-25, -20);

// This is the position you should place that sprite to have it in the right position
Vector2 spritePos = bottomRight + distFromBR;
```

Comment: Thanks, I understood your original post, except I am getting error with the getWindowManager() but I just used the getWidth() & getHeight(). I know about vectors, from a question I posted trying making my bullet work. I do have a question though, when ever I use Vector2 it tells me I need to make class or interface for it. Could you possibly clarify that part.

Comment: @Manji: I am _making an assumption_ that you have a 2D vector class and it's named `Vector2`. You might not have a 2D vector class, or it might not be named Vector2 if you do. If Android doesn't natively support a vector class, there are vector math libraries available on the internet. I don't have any recommendation as to which you should use since I don't develop in Java, but [this one](http://www.objectclub.jp/download/vecmath_e) came up in another SO question.

Comment: Android has a Vector class but it is the same as ArrayList with a few differences. Thanks for clearing that bit of information up for me :)

Comment: Right, that's the sort of vector I don't mean. I'll edit to clarify - but I mean a [mathematical vector](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Vector.html), _not_ the list type.